# How do I make swiffy animation responsive?

Tags: html, flash, twitter-bootstrap, canvas, google-swiffy

I have a swiffy animation I created and I am using bootstrap as a framework to make my website responsive, I have tried to make the animation responsive using:

```
<div class="row">
<div id="swiffycontainer" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
</div>
```

```
#swiffycontainer{
width: 100%    !important;
height: auto   !important; 
}
```

But this does not seem to work I have tried all different combinations, the only thing that gets it to re-size it adding a width or height value but then it all goes wrong with container size etc.
I have also tried:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="wrap2">

    <iframe src="animation.html" width="1280px" height="482px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>

</div>


.wrap2 {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
  padding-top: 2px;
  height: 0;
}

.wrap2 iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

But this only re-sizes the container of the animation the animation itself is still cut off.

Comment: Could you please show the code that is used to draw the video itself onto canvas (html and JavaScript). You would need to change the size of the canvas element (by CSS or optimally directly, latter also requiring you to change size used with drawImage).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any extra classes to make this happen (all those col-xx-12 class are unnecessary). My project is using Bootstrap together with Swiffy just as yours. 
Just this css is already sufficient:

```
#swiffycontainer{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; 
}
```

If that is not the case, then you need to try to use Inspect Element (on Chrome or with FireBug for Firefox) to see if the inner elements of '#swiffycontainer' affected by any other css rules.

The second method using iframe will not work because the style for 'body' inside the iframe was not specified at all. Therefore only the iframe tag was affected.